# Bootstrap 3 Collapse (right to left)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There are some posts discussing collapsing from left to right and there are some Fiddle examples [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/eT8KH/1/). But I would like the collapse to happen from right to left. Is that possible with just the code shown below.

```css
 #demo.width {
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.35s ease;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">
    Horizontal Collapsible
</button>

<div id="container" style="width:400px;height:70px;">
    <div id="demo" class="collapse in width" style="background-color:yellow;">
        <div style="padding: 20px; overflow:hidden; width:200px;">
            Here is my content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<small>Works in FF 24.0, IE 10.</small>
<br />
<b>Doesn't work in Chrome 30.0.1599.1.1</b>
<ul>
    <li>Bounces on Show</li>
    <li>Hide has no transition</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes if you add `"float:right"` to your style in this div of yours

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse in width" style="background-color:yellow;">
```

The code should look like this when you add it.

```
<div id="demo" class="collapse in width" style="background-color:yellow; float:right;">
```

If this is not what you wanted please get back to me.

Comment: yes that works somewhat. I'll accept that as my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @user1186050 if this did answer your question please accept it.